# connect two workbooks after changing file path

Tags: vba, excel, replace, excel-formula

I have a problem with connecting two excel workbooks. I have Excel1 and Excel2 and I have some information from Excel1 in Excel2, I use =[excel1.xlsm]Sheet1!$A$1 . 
But after moving this file from one computer to another file path change and it doesn´t work.
Any idea how to fix it automatically?
If I send it to someone who is not able to do it through Data - Connection.
Thank you

There would be two folders. In first folder there would be main excel and in second folder there would be about 200 workbooks. Main Excel should be connected with each of 200 workbooks.

Comment: If your file move often, you'd have to find another solution. But you can simply use Find/Replace (Ctrl+H) of Excel to fix this quickly! Find parameter = Old Path, Replace with New Path! And voilà! ;)

Comment: Are excel1.xlsm and excel2.xlsm within the same folder and are both of them moved to the other computer?

Comment: what do you mean by connecting two workbooks, is there links in one to the other?

Comment: There would be two folders. In first folder there would be main excel and in second folder there would be about 200 workbooks. Main Excel should be connected with each of 200 workbooks.

It would be connect by data -> connection